# Как вывести различия в массивах С#

Tags: c#

Я пытаюсь написать программу, которая выведет разницу между предложениями
ожидаемый результат "Магазин - лес"
но в итоге я получаю пустоту
Можете помочь с данной задачей

```
string[] array1 = { "Мама пошла в магазин" };
string[] array2 = { "Мама пошла в лес" };
var ar = array1.Where(x => array2.Any(y => y.Equals(x))).ToArray();
```

Comment: Для начала вам нужно разбить строки на массивы. Сейчас у вас каждый массив состоит из одного элемента, в котором цельная строка. А вы, наверное, хотите, чтобы пробегание было по каждому элементу в этих предложениях, правда? Это для начала

Comment: попробовал через Split но так же не получилось(

Comment: @ЮраИванов Всё что вы пробовали впредь добавляйте в вопрос. Так всем проще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
string[] array1 = "Мама пошла в магазин".Split();
string[] array2 = "Мама пошла в лес".Split();
var ar = array1.Except(array2).Concat(array2.Except(array1)).ToArray();
```

или

```
var ar = array1.Concat(array2).GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();
```